# What weapons were Rama & Lakshmana trained to use?

Tags: rama, weapon, lakshmana

Lakshmana uses a sword to mutilate the unarmed Surpanakha - but apart from that both Rama and Lakshmana seem to have only fought with bow-and-arrows.